# Тире перед "в этом"

Tags: пунктуация

Здравствуйте.

Он оригинален()в этом суть.

Ставится ли тут тире?

Есть ли разница между "это" и "в этом"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Тире здесь нужно, но не из-за "это", а потому, что здесь бессоюзное сложное предложение, между частями которого ставится тире, так как имеется нюанс следствия во второй чати, а также можно рассматривать вторую часть как неожиданное присоединение

Answer (score 1):

Он оригинален - в этом его суть.

Это БСП со значением распространения (о распространении говорит наличие местоимения "в этом"). Тире ставится вследствие разной структуры предложений (второе предложение неполное).

В таких предложениях возможна запятая, например: Был, словом, у Понтия Пилата, за это я ручаюсь.

Сравнить: Оригинальность - это его суть. Оригинальность - в этом его суть. Это простые предложения, связки: ЭТО, также (на правах связки) В ЭТОМ.